# Need method to replicate "argpartition" for masked arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

As the title indicates I want to use `numpy.argpartition` on a masked array.  I can, but `.argpartition` does not honor the mask (it emits a warning message notifying the user as well).  This is not useful since the masked data corrupt the results of `.argpartition`.
Any suggestions for replacement methods?  I need to know the indices of the *k* smallest values in a large 1D array.

Current ideas:

a) write my own implementation of `.argpartition` for masked arrays

b) my current data set has the feature that the masked values are all negative (which is why they corrupt the search for smallest values).
which leads to two solutions

1. I could sort through them and assign a very large number to the masked values...If I do this, I feel I could just drop used of masked arrays.
2. I could count the number of masked elements = *p* and then `argpartition` on *p+k* elements.  Removing the *p* elements from the list.

Neither a) or b) seem very pythonic or elegant.

Comment: Why not just partition the unmasked elements?

Comment: Um, I don't understand your suggestion.  `.partition` sorts the values, but I need indices, hence the use of `.argpartition`.  Regardless, `.partition` ignores the mask as well.

Comment: +1 on this question. If i would just remove the masekd element in the array i would ruine the orginal indxing of the array, hence, one has be able to do `àrgpartion` without losing the orginal indices. Same as it does not consider the masked elemnts if one does np.argmax() .